# MySQL Conditional Where Clause

Tags: mysql

I'm try to output listings in a single query based on the specific language selected.  But what I need to do is if the listing is not available for the selected language, then it would return the the English one if that exists.

So if English is 'en' and Japanese is 'jp', the following currently returns the Japanese listings:

```
SELECT * 
FROM listings LS
LEFT JOIN listing_langs LANG ON LS.listing_id = LANG.listing_id
WHERE LANG.language = 'jp'
```

I'm trying to figure out it even possible in MySQL to set up the query so that it would first look for: LANG.language = 'jp', and return the Japanese listing (as it does now), but if that comes up empty to then look for: LANG.language = 'en' and instead return that English listing if it exists.

So basically, return the Japanese listing if it exists, but if it doesn't then default to the English listing if that exists.

Comment: You may need to create a derived query using a CASE statement on the language condition, by joining the `jp` and `en` sub-queries together where `jp` is not matched. My original answer did not solve your problem, so I flagged it for deletion.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I'm not sure how to do the derived query, but will keep trying to see what will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM listings LS
LEFT JOIN listing_langs LANG ON (LS.listing_id = LANG.listing_id AND LANG.language = 'jp' OR 
    (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM listing_langs WHERE listing_langs.listing_id = LS.listing_id AND listing_langs.language = 'jp') AND LANG.language = 'en')
```

That is, explicitly check in the JOIN to see if there is no row for `jp` and if not, then use `en`.

It's a big ugly, but it does succinctly capture the essence of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks!  I just tried a quick test, and that worked out fine, showing Japanese if it was there, or substituting English if it wasn't.  I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT        * 
FROM          listings LS
  LEFT JOIN   listing_langs LANG
  ON          LS.listing_id = LANG.listing_id
WHERE         LANG.language = IFNULL(SELECT language FROM listing_langs WHERE language = 'jp','en')
```

Without testing (or being able to test) i think the `IFNULL` command in mysql should be great for this.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do

```
(SELECT *, 1 as grade  
FROM listings LS  
LEFT JOIN listing_langs LANG ON LS.listing_id = LANG.listing_id  
WHERE LANG.language = 'jp')   
UNION  
(SELECT *, 2 as grade   
FROM listings LS  
LEFT JOIN listing_langs LANG ON LS.listing_id = LANG.listing_id  
WHERE LANG.language = 'en')  
ORDER BY grade LIMIT 1
```

You will always have just one row if `jp` if exists, otherwise `en` if it does not exist.

Sorry for the previous mistake.

Comment: First should be 'jp' only and second 'en' only, else you may get the 'en' record first

Comment: When i posted for the first time i made a mistake (i had in both query land = 'jp' OR lang='en' - i corrected that)

Comment: Thanks, I'm sorry I didn't make it clearer that I would have several listings.  So this works with just one listing, but if there are more it will show both English and Japanese if they both exist (But in that case I would only want to return the Japanese one).

Comment: I'm not sure i understand exactly "So this works with just one listing, but if there are more it will show both English and Japanese if they both exist" - the query above will always return only 1 row because of LIMIT 1 at the end. If jp and english exists the ORDER BY clause will put jp first (because grade=1 for 'jp' and grade=2 for 'en')

Comment: Sorry, I mean that the query usually returns many listings.  When specifying Japanese, I want to show the Japanese version, but if there is no Japanese version for the specific listing, then use the English version instead.